# How do you configure IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength in GreyFace's mm6 mod?

Tags: might-and-magic-6-mandate-of-heaven

The patch notes say

> 'Increases rate of Recovery' enchantment now works. IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength controls how much it increases the rate. Default is 10%.

But it doesn't say what to put in the config file to use it. Say I wanted to make it 50% (like the original game intended.) Would I put `IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength=50` or `IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength=50%` or `IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength=.5` or how does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to source code, this value has type of "int" (see [script in github repo](https://github.com/GrayFace/MMExtension/blob/master/Scripts/Structs/00%20structs.lua)):

> int  'IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength'  Info "[MM6]"

This means it cannot be "50%" or ".5", so correct usage is:

```
IncreaseRecoveryRateStrength=50
```